# Why isnt this HTML Form valid?

Tags: html, forms, validation

Hi recently i started a course, Ive been able to troubleshoot all my other validation errors, but i cant see why this wont validate with w3?

```
<div id="conform">
<form method="post" action="" id="form1">
 Name:  <input type="text" name="first_name" /><br></br>
Subject: <input type="text" name="department" id="department"/><br></br>
    Department:
     Sales  <input type="radio" name="red" id="red"/>
     Support    <input type="radio" name="amber" id="amber"/>
     Other  <input type="radio" name="red" id="green"/><br></br>
     Content:   <textarea name="details" id="messagedetails" cols="30">
     </textarea><br></br>
     <input type="submit"  value="Submit"/>
</form>
</div>
```

If someone could explain this to me.. Thanks

Hi I should add, these are the main errors im getting; http://puu.sh/u1Oo

Theyre all similiar to that.

Comment: What validation errors do you get?

Comment: Don't they tell you why it didn't validate?

Comment: Use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/).  It will tell you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know *why* it doesn't validate with w3c, I suggest you visit this site:

http://validator.w3.org/check

They're very clear about why it's wrong. Also, seeing their report, it amazes me that browsers can make sense of HTML at all =p

**edit** the errors that you are left with are because in HTML you should enclose text and input fields with a block level element, such as div, p, etc.

Comment: Yeah, HTML is a kluge on a hack.  Shoulda been tossed ten years ago.  And it doesn't help that MS insists on having their own version, different from the others.

Comment: @HotLicks Amen; the browser forgiveness almost reaches godlike levels, making me pity their developers =/

Comment: Yeah i couldnt understand the jargon! :)

Answer (score 1):

break is a self closing tag, ie instead of `<br></br>` you can you use just `<br/>`

Comment: it could also be that your form action is empty. you may want to add an action or remove it entirely

Answer (score 0):

You did not post the document type so I will assume HTML5.

1. It is missing semantic markup such as meta information and required attributes.
2. There is no place for the results (Which may not apply if this is doing a legacy post back)
3. See reasons 1 and 2

*Update*

Please see the following links in relation to the above points:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/html5forms/

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_form_attributes.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_reference.asp

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-cross-browser-html5-forms/

http://www.video2brain.com/en/videos-13589.htm

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Forms_in_HTML

Comment: Hi could you recommend where i can learn about the meta info and attributes in relation to forms? FYI the form just needs to sit, its not a functional one because we haven't learned that yet on the course! :)

Answer (score 0):

What @Keith said, use `<br/>` instead of `<br></br>`. Also, `form[action]` can't be empty; even if you don't use it (i.e. if you intercept the submit by JS), you need to have something in there. Usually it's `"#"`.

Answer (score 0):

your radio buttons should have the same name

Comment: Kieronboz probably intended the 3  &lt;radio&gt; elements to have the same name attribute.  But different names won't make HTML invalid.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I saw from the validator apart from the other issues listed above

> Bad value for attribute action on element form: Must be non-empty.
>    Syntax of IRI reference: Any
>   URL. For example: /hello, #canvas, or http://example.org/. Characters
>   should be represented in NFC and spaces should be escaped as %20.

Answer (score 0):

[Validity is very relative](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/validation.html): it means conformance to a formalized syntax definition called Document Type Definition (DTD), at least in classic HTML including XHTML (HTML5 drafts have their own ideas about validity).

The published DTD that your code snippet mostly corresponds to is XHTML 1.0 Transitional. Using it, the only error reported by the validator is this (and rather self-explanatory):

required attribute "rows" not specified

```
 Content:   <textarea name="details" id="messagedetails" cols="30">
```

This does not mean that the markup would be otherwise fine. Validity is a formal thing and does not imply even correctness, still less quality. For one thing, the use of `<br></br>`, while formally valid in XHTML, violates the (in)famous [Appendix C](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#guidelines) of the XHTML 1.0 specification:

“C.2. Empty Elements

Include a space before the trailing / and > of empty elements, e.g. `<br />`, `<hr />` and `<img src="karen.jpg" alt="Karen" />`. Also, use the minimized tag syntax for empty elements, e.g. `<br />`, as the alternative syntax `<br></br>` allowed by XML gives uncertain results in many existing user agents.”